# using regex to return integer from string within integer range

Tags: regex

I am trying to capture the last numbers from "hpercent=" in the string but only if it falls into a range from 1-25.

**sample strings:**

- ipercent=11 | hpercent=10
- ipercent=21 | hpercent=25
- ipercent=10 | hpercent=42
- ipercent=2  | hpercent=2
- ipercent=15 | hpercent=80
- ipercent=56 | hpercent=89

**desired output from "hpercent":** 
10, 25, 2

**I tried:**

- Get the last digits: [^=]+(?=$)
- My range for only numbers 1-25: ^[1-9]$|^1[0-9]$|^2[0-5]$

just not sure how to put the above regex together in one expression

UPDATE:

Sorry, very new to this. but I guess I need to capture the last number as a group. but as you can see when it captures the last number it IS beyond 25.

- This captures everything but also the 6 in 26: [1-9]$|^1[0-9]$|^2[0-5]$
- This captures everything but not single digits: ^[1-9]$|1[0-9]$|2[0-5]$

I should only capture between 1-25.

[Adobe Classifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPjAI.png)

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: [`hpercent=([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-5])(?:[^0-9]|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/qC4mY1/1)

Comment: I am using pure regular expressions for classifying data in Adobe Analytics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work `hpercent=([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-5])(?![0-9])`

Expanded

```
 hpercent=
 ( [1-9] | 1 [0-9] | 2 [0-5] )  # (1)
 (?! [0-9] )
```

Simplified by a number range regex generator *[tool](http://www.regexformat.com/version_files/Rx5_ScrnSht0.jpg)*

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify what's your regex flavor nor programming language you're using, here's a solution using vim:

```
/\v\=(\d|1\d|2[0-5])$/
```

**What's going on**:

- only capture things comprised between `=` and `EOL` (`$`)
- then capture:

  - a single digit from 1 to 9, **or**
  - a 1 followed by any digit (so 10 up to 19), **or**
  - a 2 followed by anything from 0 to 5 (so anything from 20 up to 25)

It should be easy to convert this to your regex flavor.

Answer (score 0):

Just to put your regexes together in one expression:

```
/([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-5])(?=$)/
```

Comment: What is the difference between a look-ahead for end of string (`$`), and just the end of string by itself?